# Number is undefined in array using React Js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to iterate through an array, but for some reason my number is being returned as undefined when assigning it.

JS that does not work:

```
const Logos = Array(4).fill("").map((a, p) =>
            <div key={ p } className="columns is-centered">
                <div className="column is-12-mobile is-10-tablet is-10-widescreen">
                    <div className="columns is-multiline is-mobile is-centered logos">
                        { posts[0].node.frontmatter.logos[p + 1] }
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Expected Result would be:
...logos1
...logos2
...logos3
...logos4

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

This works, but I need to iterate through all 4 and not return the same one 4 times.

```
const Logos = Array(4).fill("").map((a, p) =>
            <div key={ p } className="columns is-centered">
                <div className="column is-12-mobile is-10-tablet is-10-widescreen">
                    <div className="columns is-multiline is-mobile is-centered logos">
                        { posts[0].node.frontmatter.logos1}
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Try `posts[0].node.frontmatter["logos" + (p + 1)]`

Comment: Legend!!!! Thank you @DoronBrikman!!!